Consistency of Runge-Kutta methods
Consider the Runge-Kutta method given by
\begin{equation*}
    y_{n+1} = y_n + \Delta t \phi(t_n,y_n,\Delta t),
\end{equation*}
with
\begin{equation*}
    \phi(t_n, y_n, \Delta t) = \sum_{i=1}^s b_i k_i,
\end{equation*}
and, for $i=1,2,\dots,s$,
\begin{align}
k_i = f(t_n+c_i\Delta t, y_n+ \Delta t \sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}k_{j}).
\end{align}
In the book [1], this method is said to be consistent with an initial value problem if $\phi(t_n,y_n,0) \equiv f(t_n,y_n)$. From this definition, how can I prove that a Runge-Kutta method is consistent if and only if
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=1}^s b_i = 1?
\end{equation}
I attempted it this way, but I don't think it's correct, and I feel like I'm going in circles:
Initially, suppose that a Runge-Kutta method is consistent with the IVP. Then, it holds that
\begin{align}
    f(t_n,y_n) = \phi(t_n,y_n,0)
               = \sum_{i=1}^s b_i  f(t_n+c_i \cdot 0, y_n+ 0 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}k_{j}) 
               = \sum_{i=1}^s b_i  f(t_n,y_n) 
               = f(t_n,y_n) \sum_{i=1}^s b_i
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=1}^s b_i = 1.
\end{equation}
Suppose now that
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=1}^s b_i = 1.
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{align}
     \phi(t_n,y_n,0) = \sum_{i=1}^s b_i  f(t_n+c_i \cdot 0, y_n+ 0 \cdot \sum_{j=1}^s a_{ij}k_{j}) 
           = \sum_{i=1}^s b_i  f(t_n,y_n) 
           = f(t_n,y_n) \sum_{i=1}^s b_i 
           =  f(t_n,y_n).
\end{align}
References
[1] Lambert, J. D. Computational Methods in Ordinary Differential Equations. John Wiley & Sons, 1973.

Note that $\phi(t_n,y_n) = (\sum_i b_i) f(t_n,x_n)$. The equivalence should be straightforward to see from this.
